# jQuery make child div visible on hover (on effective li element only, not parent!)

Tags: jquery

I've already tried all of the existing posts related to this, but they doesn't work as I want it...

The HTML:

```
<ol class="sortable">
<li>
    <div>
        <a href="#">Start Page</a>
        <div class="li_options">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/small_add.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" onClick="[..]"><img src="img/icons/small_remove.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <div>
                <a href="#">Sub Seite</a>
                <div class="li_options">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/small_add.png" /></a>
                    <a href="#" onClick="[..]"><img src="img/icons/small_remove.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#">Sub Sub Seite</a>
                        <div class="li_options">
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/small_add.png" /></a>
                            <a href="#" onClick="[..]"><img src="img/icons/small_remove.png" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

This should look like this:

- Start Page

  - Sub Page

    - Sub Page

I want the div.li_options which is set for every li element to be shown only on hovering element. I know, that the parent's li is also being "hovered" on hovering child elements, but I don't those "li_options" to be displayed.

The best solution so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('.sortable li').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).children().children('.li_options').show();
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).children().children('.li_options').hide();
    });
});
```

But with this, parents aren't being excluded... I don't know how to point on them, because there can be endless levels. Do you know how to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/sm8vS/

**Updated version** http://jsfiddle.net/36cV3/

**OR like this =>** http://jsfiddle.net/N6xqm/ (Smaller way)

*Extra* Also you can look few plugins by the name of tree view menu. - if need be or if you are looking for something like this: http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

*Behaviour* hover over `Start Page` => `Sub Seite` will appear, Now hover over `Sub Seite` => => `Sub Sub Seite` will appear.

For better parsing I added - `sub-menu` and `sub-sub-menu` class in your respective menu structure. rest code is as below.

Hope it fits your needs `:)`

**Another much small way to do** http://jsfiddle.net/N6xqm/ `:)`

```
(function($) {

    $('.li_options').hide();
        $('a').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).next('.li_options').show();
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $('.li_options').hide();
        });

})(jQuery);​
```

**Sample code**

```
    (function($) {

    $('.li_options').hide();
    $('.sortable li').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find('ol').show();
        anchor_hover();
    }).mouseout(function() {
        anchor_hover();
        $(this).find('ol').hide();
    });

    function anchor_hover() {
        $('a').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).next('.li_options').show();
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $('.li_options').hide();
        });

    }


})(jQuery);​
```

**HTML**

```
<ol class="sortable">
<li>
    <div>
        <a href="#">Start Page</a>
        <div class="li_options">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/small_add.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" onClick="[..]"><img src="img/icons/small_remove.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <ol class="sub-menu">
        <li>
            <div>
                <a href="#">Sub Seite</a>
                <div class="li_options">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/small_add.png" /></a>
                    <a href="#" onClick="[..]"><img src="img/icons/small_remove.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <ol class="sub-sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#">Sub Sub Seite</a>
                        <div class="li_options">
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/small_add.png" /></a>
                            <a href="#" onClick="[..]"><img src="img/icons/small_remove.png" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
<div class="clear"></div>​
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the entire list is always displayed, it's the div.li_options which only should be displayed on hovering. Because there is no level limit, ol classes like "sub-menu" and "sub-sub-menu" aren't that efficient, but relizable if unconditionally needed.

Comment: I hit the enter key to fast, so I was editing my reply. Don't know if you get this change, so the next reply to verify you'll be informed ;) we're close i think, hope you find a solution for this.. :(

Comment: @Dennis All good man, `:)`oh okies, so when user will hover `Startpage` the whole sub-menu and sub-submenu will be displayed? and only lioptions shoulde be displayed on hovering the respective list element `:)` let me know if I understand it correct, I will fix it, that will be easy to fix.

Comment: Almost, yes. The hole tree is being displayed all the time and only the li.options, as you said, should be displayed on hovering :)

Comment: @Dennis Cooloes => **LIke this working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/sm8vS/2/ ? Done man! `:)`

Comment: Sorry if it's hard to understand me, but it's not easy to explain :) A picture paints a thousand words: [Picture of tree menu](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/6405/79827827.jpg). You see what I mean? The menu is display all the time, but only div.li_options shows up on hovering the effective li element.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18676/discussion-between-dennis-and-tats-innit)

Comment: @Dennis lol do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sm8vS/3/ `:))` we will get there!

Comment: Tats_innit solved my problem with this: http://jsfiddle.net/fNNkF/3/. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Dennis Glad it helped `:)` much smaller way : http://jsfiddle.net/N6xqm/ rest the code above should help! night night now!

Answer (score 0):

shortest way would be

```
$('.sortable li').mouseover(function(e) {
    $( '> div > .li_options', $(this) ).show();
    e.stopPropagation();
}).mouseout(function(e) {
    $( '> div > .li_options', $(this) ).hide();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```